# How to mantain the original data after using the .filter() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

This is my data : https://api.myjson.com/bins/r82tg

I use the .filter() method to filter according to its name,

```
 var filteredData = data;
 var children = filteredData.children;
 filteredData.children = children.filter(children => children.name != d.name);
```

But when I console.log my original data. It also still gets filtered. Why is that? How do I mantain my original data array before filtering?

Comment: You are reassigning `filteredData.children`. Maybe you should reassign `children` instead: `children = children.filter(children => children.name != d.name);` or save to a different variable.

Comment: @MarkMeyer data is still being filtered as well even if I reassigned children. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 data = {
   id: 30,
   children: [
    { name: "stack"}, 
    {name:"overflow"}
   ]
 }
 
 
 var filteredData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
 var children = filteredData.children;
 filteredData.children = children.filter(children => children.name != "stack");
 
 console.log(filteredData)
 console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable by using a deep copy,

```
let cloned = filteredData.children.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
filteredData.children = cloned.filter(children => children.name != d.name);
```

Comment: Does not work. The variable data still gets filtered as well. I want the data variable to mantain the original array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because your data is an object and you are assingning it to an variable by reference, you need to clone your data before filtering it like

```
 var filteredData = {...data};
 var children = filteredData.children;
 filteredData= {...filteredData, children: children.filter(children => children.name != d.name);
```